# Cannot resolve symbol @dimen/activity_horizontal_margin

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Im following this tutorial on parsing JSON within Android

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

when I copy and paste the data from list_item.xml I get "cannot resolve symbol" and google searches are yielding nothing

Comment: The question itself saying `@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin
` check in your dimen file is added or not?

Comment: Check your dimen.xml for entry `activity_horizontal_margin` google won't find it only you can .

Comment: Add dimen in dimen file or remove this line `android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"` write instead `android:padding="16dp"`

Comment: I don't really know what you mean, where is the dimen.xml or do I have to create it myself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please add this line into your `dimens.xml`

```xml
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
```

you can give whatever value you want instead of 16dp

if you have not created `dimens.xml`, you can create it in `values.xml` folder.

Answer (score -1):

hope this helps:

```xml
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
```

you can put whatever value you want instead of 16dp

if you haven't yet created dimens.xml, create it in values.xml folder.

Comment: This seems to copy [the answer by chandani c patel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48002334/466862), adding a vertical margin that wasn't asked for.